# Choosing right machine learning algorithm for human activity recognition

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

I have to analyze body movement data came from a gyroscobe and a accelerometer that are attached to arm and collected data for one week.

Using this model set my program should decide body's current status like laying , walking , climbing stairs and so on.

My question is , is there any specific machine learning algorithm that suits well to problem i have.

It is probably not a properly asked question but i am very beginner to field and currently do not have time to go through a decent learning process.
So any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A natural model for your problem is a Hidden Markov Model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) because the value you want to predict at a moment ( body's current status ) depends on the previous body state and the current indirect observations (gyroscope and accelerometer data) . In this model the hidden states are the body states and the observations are the  gyroscope and accelerometer measurements . For training and prediction you can find good implementations in a lot of languages.

Here is a paper that can be useful https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/154274182.pdf .

A simpler approach , but less accurate (in principle) is to use a multi-class classifier - a class = a state of the body .